# Make the bottom corner of the GUI Box stay on place

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am sorry if the title is ugly.

The thing is: I already make the GUI Box in the Unity like this:

[image]

If you see on the **Image 2**, there is an empty space on there, and I don't want to be like that. What I want is the bottom corner is stay on place like the **Image 1**, only the top corner of it is growing, but the bottom stays on place.

Here is an example image (taken from Heroes of Newerth):

[image]

If you see on the **Image 1**, the bottom corner of the Box that have texts on it, are stays on the bottom corner of the screen, and if you look at the **Image 2** and compare it with **Image 1**, only the top corner of the Box that are growing to the top (minus with the screen resolution) and the bottom corner stays on the bottom corner of the screen resolution.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
string textOnBox = "This is an example on how does the text on the box is align.\nMy Name is ....\nI am new at Unity and want to learn more about Unity to create and publish my own game using this engine.";
    GUIStyle style;
    GUIContent boxText;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        boxText = new GUIContent("" + textOnBox);

        GUI.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.9f);

        style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.box);
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;

        Rect boxGUI = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(boxText, "Box");

        boxGUI.x = Screen.width / 2 + 50;
        boxGUI.y = Screen.height / 2 + 200;

        GUI.Box(boxGUI, boxText, style);
    }
```

Your answer much appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the fontsize from your style could be used to determine the size of the box for 3 lines of text for the height you could do

```
style.fontSize * 3;
```